# Ajax call keeps failing pointing to error in vendor directory post application upgrade

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

I have upgraded to Pimcore11. However I am unable to see assets, DataObjects and Documents.
While looking through the Network calls I found that `GET /admin/user/get-current-user?_dc...` call keeps failing and returns a 500 Internal Server Error

Looking through the logs I found the following.

`php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFieldDefinitions() on null {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getFieldDefinitions() on null at \\vendor\\pimcore\\pimcore\\models\\DataObject\\Concrete.php:544)"} []`

`request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Error: "Call to a member function getFieldDefinitions() on null" at \vendor\pimcore\pimcore\models\DataObject\Concrete.php line 544 {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function getFieldDefinitions() on null at \\vendor\\pimcore\\pimcore\\models\\DataObject\\Concrete.php:544)"} []`

I tried to get a stack trace using Xdebug and Netbeans. However the application page take forever to load and has not been of any help.

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: @Kolyunya I am using `PHP 8.2.0 ` .  if required, I use `php_xdebug-3.2.2-8.2-vs16-nts-x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

Try following the upgrade instructions for Pimcore 11. They might have introduced breaking changes into the public API.

Your code that uses the library might be correct for the older versions of the library, but might be incorrect for the latest one.